# float64 written to nan in netcdf4

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am trying to fill data into netcdf file from a import csv file, the data is either 0 or 1.39e-14 form. upon running the code, the netcdf file is created but it is having NaN values as error message shown by panoply.

```
import numpy as np

import netCDF4

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('C:/data/new1.nc',mode='w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

lat_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lat', 361) # latitude axis

lon_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lon', 721) # longitude axis


lat = ncfile.createVariable('lat', np.float32, ('lat',))

lat.units = 'degrees_north'

lat.long_name = 'latitude'

lon = ncfile.createVariable('lon', np.float32, ('lon',))

lon.units = 'degrees_east'

lon.long_name = 'longitude'

emission = ncfile.createVariable('emission',np.float64,('lat','lon')) 

emission.units = 'tonn' 

emission.standard_name = 'tonn/month' 

from numpy import genfromtxt

my_data = genfromtxt('2100.csv', delimiter=',')   

lat[:]=-90. + (.5)*np.arange(361)   

lon[:]= -180 + (.5)*np.arange(721)

emission[:,:] = my_data

ncfile.close
```

Comment: so you mean that you get `NaNs` in the variable 'emission' whilst having no `NaN` specified in your input data? Did you check 'my_data'?

Comment: Also you can consider calling `np.genfromtxt()` with additional parameters like `dtype` or `missing_values`, see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Comment: my_data has values ranging from 0 to 1 and no NaN. i checked the data and even emission array too. and when i'm plotting the generated netcdf file in panoply the error pops up as "error preparing the plot. failed creating the data handler : Axis includes NaN value" . @MrFuppes

Comment: one more detail: it's `ncfile.close()`, not `ncfile.close`. Or even better: use Python's `with` syntax. Then, can you load the nc file that your code writes back into Python and check the variable for NaNs? E.g. `~np.isfinite(emission)` should return [].

Comment: Thanx man, Its working now. @ MrFuppes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an illustration of my comment above, better use `with` syntax.

```py
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

file = 'D:/test/new1.nc'
with Dataset(file, mode='w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC') as ncfile:
    lat_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lat', 361) # latitude axis
    lon_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lon', 721) # longitude axis
    lat = ncfile.createVariable('lat', np.float32, ('lat',))
    lat.units = 'degrees_north'
    lat.long_name = 'latitude'
    lon = ncfile.createVariable('lon', np.float32, ('lon',))
    lon.units = 'degrees_east'
    lon.long_name = 'longitude'
    lat[:]=-90. + (.5)*np.arange(361)   
    lon[:]= -180 + (.5)*np.arange(721)
    emission = ncfile.createVariable('emission',np.float64,('lat','lon')) 
    emission.units = 'tonn' 
    emission.standard_name = 'tonn/month' 
    emission[:,:] = np.zeros((len(lat_dim),len(lon_dim))) # fake data
```

checking the input e.g. with

```py
with Dataset(file, mode='r') as d:
    v = np.array(d.variables['emission'][:,:])
```

...gives me

```py
In [58]: np.any(~np.isfinite(v))
Out[58]: False
```

so everything is fine as it should be, only finite values. I can also open and plot this in Panoply of course.